# How to play a Sound through External Speaker in vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, audio

I have a button called 'btnLogin' on my form, and want to play a 'beep' sound when this button is pressed.

I have already attempted the 'Beep()' command, but this will only play through the motherboard, and not any external speakers.

How could i make this button command work?

Comment: Thanks! @Jhuliano Moreno! Just what I needed and the web didn't have a proper answer!

Comment: If he answered your question. Please accept his answer by clicking the check mark next to his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use MSDN as a reference when trying to code things in .NET framework, they have a pretty extensive documentation with example and usual stuff you would need.

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav")
```

From: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y171b18(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y171b18%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)